# Error: Service(Telemetry(IoError(Custom {...... error in substrate

Tags: blockchain, substrate, polkadot

**Full error message:-**

```
Error: Service(Telemetry(IoError(Custom { kind: Other, error: "Error parsing resolv.conf: ProtoError { kind: Msg(\"Malformed label: --\") }" })))
```

Got the above error while running the node in staging mode and it is working fine in dev mode.

**How did I run it in staging mode:-**

Firstly extracted customspec file using below command-

```
./target/release/substrate build-spec --disable-default-bootnode --chain staging > customSpec.json
```

After I have made few changes to it (changed staking,session and balances configurations)
and then I have converted it into customSpecRaw file using below command

```
./target/release/substrate build-spec --chain=customSpec.json --raw --disable-default-bootnode > customSpecRaw.json
```

Then I got the output as

```
2021-09-21 02:46:00 Low open file descriptor limit configured for the process. Current value: 4096, recommended value: 10000.    
2021-09-21 02:46:01 Building chain spec    
2021-09-21 02:46:01 [0]  generated 1 npos voters, 1 from validators and 0 nominators    
2021-09-21 02:46:01 [0]  generated 1 npos voters, 1 from validators and 0 nominators    
2021-09-21 02:46:01 [0]  new validator set of size 1 has been processed for era 1
```

and after this I started the node using-

```
./target/release/substrate   --base-path /tmp/node01   --chain ./customSpecRaw.json   --port 30333   --ws-port 9945   --rpc-port 9933   --telemetry-url 'wss://telemetry.polkadot.io/submit/ 0'   --validator   --rpc-methods Unsafe   --name MyNode01
```

then got this error-

```
2021-09-21 08:46:29 Low open file descriptor limit configured for the process. Current value: 4096, recommended value: 10000.    
2021-09-21 08:46:29 Substrate Node    
2021-09-21 08:46:29 ✌️  version 3.0.0-dev-e30db04a7-x86_64-linux-gnu    
2021-09-21 08:46:29 ❤️  by Parity Technologies <admin@parity.io>, 2017-2021    
2021-09-21 08:46:29  Chain specification: Staging Testnet    
2021-09-21 08:46:29  Node name: MyNode01    
2021-09-21 08:46:29  Role: AUTHORITY    
2021-09-21 08:46:29  Database: RocksDb at /tmp/node01/chains/staging_testnet/db/full    
2021-09-21 08:46:29 ⛓  Native runtime: node-267 (substrate-node-1.tx2.au10)    
Error: Service(Telemetry(IoError(Custom { kind: Other, error: "Error parsing resolv.conf: ProtoError { kind: Msg(\"Malformed label: --\") }" })))
```

I am not able to solve this error ..... any useful hacks??

Comment: Your `resolv.conf` is not being parsed. This is located at `/etc/resolv.conf`. What do the contents look like? Someone had a [similar](https://github.com/bluejekyll/trust-dns/issues/644) issue on github.

Comment: Is it a system file or file in substrate....can I get full address of the file location....I have been stuck at this from 2 days

Comment: On [unix](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/resolv.conf.5.html) like systems it's located at `/etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: s i have deleted and re installed it....but same result